# How to catch all checked exceptions (in a single block) in Java 6?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, runtimeexception, checked-exceptions

**IMPORTANT: This question only relates to Java 6 (and below).**

The hierarchy [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_hierarchy.shtml) shows Java `Exception`s are divided into two types: `RuntimeException` and *[not a RuntimeException]*:

[image: Java exceptions hierarchy]

Would it not have been better to divide into something like `UncheckedException` and `CheckedException` instead? For example, the following statement has quite a few checked exceptions:

```
try {
    transaction.commit();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
} catch (RollbackException e) {
} catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
} catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
} catch (SystemException e) {
}
```

Am only really interested in whether it succeeds or fails so would like to deal with the checked exceptions as a group but not the unchecked exceptions as it's not good practice to catch an unexpected error. So with this in mind, maybe I could do something like:

```
try {
    transaction.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
        // Throw unchecked exception
        throw e;
    }
    // Handle checked exception
    // ...
}
```

But this seems horribly hacky. Is there a better way?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? (Java 7 has additional features around this.)

Comment: Oooh - didn't know that! I'm using 1.6.

Comment: Worth noting that Java exceptions are actually divided into not two but three types RuntimeException, Exceptions that are not RuntimeExceptions and Errors.

Comment: Hmmmm not *strictly* true as an Error isn't an Exception.

Comment: Correct, I did not think about that seperation, I'm guessing a more correct thing to say would have been "Java throwables are divided into three parts"

Comment: Alternatively it could be RuntimeException and CheckException or something like this, was also confused that RuntimeExcepions are a subclass of the checked Exception and now wondering how to catch only all checked ones, after figuring out my mistake. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then you are almost there. Just catch RuntimeException. That will catch RuntimeException and everything under it in the hierarchy. Then a fallthrough for Exception, and you're covered:

```
try {
    transaction.commit();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // Throw unchecked exception
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle checked exception
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Like it. I still wonder why they didn't include a category for "NonRuntimeException" but this does the job.

Comment: Worth noting that this is not the _Java way_ (that is, it is not very _Java_ to catch very general exception types). That said I personally think this is fine and that java got exceptions wrong.

Answer (score 5):

`Java 7` allows you such constructions:

```
try {
    transaction.commit();
} catch (SecurityException | IllegalStateException  | RollbackException | HeuristicMixedException  e ) {
   // blablabla
}
```

**UPD:** I think, that there isn't nice and convenient way for doing it in earlier versions of Java. That is why developers of `Java` language introduced such construction in `Java 7`. So, you could devise your own approaches for `Java 6`.

Comment: OP specifically said he is using version 1.6 and not 1.7

Comment: Lovely, I was wondering if something like that existed! Good to know they've improved it in 7 but unfortunately I'm confined to 6. Kind of makes the question redundant though I suppose!

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum He said it after I posted my answer. Do you think that I should immediately delete my answer?

Comment: @Andremoniy No, I think it's a good answer that will help future users, I made that comment so you'd hopefully add something about the java 1.6 case in it as well. Also, here is a good link illustrating the added functionality in 1.7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Comment: Can't we able to have a parent class to all this exceptions

Answer (score -1):

I gave a similar answer in another post, so yes, it is copy past:

Something that I do is to have a static method that handles all exceptions and I add the log to a JOptionPane to show it to the user, but you could write the result to a file in `FileWriter` wraped in a `BufeeredWriter`.
For the main static method, to catch the Uncaught Exceptions I do:

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Initializations...
    }
});


Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( 
    new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException( Thread t, Throwable ex ) {
            handleExceptions( ex, true );
        }
    }
);
```

And as for the method:

```java
public static void handleExceptions( Throwable ex, boolean shutDown ) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,
        "A CRITICAL ERROR APPENED!\n",
        "SYSTEM FAIL",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ex.toString());
    for (StackTraceElement ste : ex.getStackTrace()) {
        sb.append("\n\tat ").append(ste);
    }


    while( (ex = ex.getCause()) != null ) {
        sb.append("\n");
        for (StackTraceElement ste : ex.getStackTrace()) {
            sb.append("\n\tat ").append(ste);
        }
    }

    String trace = sb.toString();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,
        "PLEASE SEND ME THIS ERROR SO THAT I CAN FIX IT. \n\n" + trace,
        "SYSTEM FAIL",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    if( shutDown ) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exit( 0 );
    }
}
```

In you case, instead of "screaming" to the user, you could write a log like I told you before:

```java
String trace = sb.toString();

File file = new File("mylog.txt");
FileWriter myFileWriter = null;
BufferedWriter myBufferedWriter = null;

try {
    //with FileWriter(File file, boolean append) you can writer to 
    //the end of the file
    myFileWriter = new FileWriter( file, true );
    myBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter( myFileWriter );

    myBufferedWriter.write( trace );
}
catch ( IOException ex1 ) {
    //Do as you want. Do you want to use recursive to handle 
    //this exception? I don't advise that. Trust me...
}
finally {
    try {
        myBufferedWriter.close();
    }
    catch ( IOException ex1 ) {
        //Idem...
    }

    try {
        myFileWriter.close();
    }
    catch ( IOException ex1 ) {
        //Idem...
    }
}
```

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)